# Writing connector for sugarCRM

Tags: rest, crm, sugarcrm

I am writing a custom connector for sugarCRM and had a few doubts.

What I am doing is writing directly to the following directory on my server

```
./custom/modules/Connectors/connectors/sources/ext<protocol type>/<main dir>/
```

Am I correct in understanding that there is no need to load and install it as a zip file using module loader?

What exactly does the formatter directory in the connector do?

Also I found multiple sugar developer guides on their website http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/
Are the previous ones outdated. Am I wrong in following the old guides, because they seem to explain better.

Any other links are also a great help.